# How to get array of object from smart contract using Nethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nethereum

I have function in smart contract:

```
 struct DrugBox {
        uint256 weight; // weight is accumulated by delegation
        uint256 creationDate;
        address producer;
        string drugName;
        uint256 id;
    }
  function getAllBoxes() public view returns (DrugBox[] memory box1)  {
        return boxes;
    }
```

And I have code in C#. I want to return list of drug boxes from smart contract

```
    [FunctionOutput]
    public class DrugBoxesDTO 
    {
        [Parameter("tuple[]", "box1", 1)]
        public List<DrugBoxDTO> Boxes { get; set; }
    }

    public class DrugBoxDTO 
    {
        public string DrugName { get; set; }
        public string Producer { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; } 
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

Task<DrugBoxesDTO> qwe = drugStoreContract.GetFunction("getAllBoxes").CallAsync<DrugBoxesDTO>();
```

But I get an error:

```
System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=One or more errors occurred. (Arrays containing Dynamic Types are not supported)

Inner Exception 1:
NotSupportedException: Arrays containing Dynamic Types are not supported
```

How to deserialize list of object correctly?

Answer (score 1):

For the fields in **DrugBoxDTO** class, you need to add **Parameter** attribute as well.
And for Id & Weight fields, use BigInteger instead of int, since you use uint256 in contract.

```
public class DrugBoxDTO 
{
    [Parameter("uint256", "weight", 1)]
    public BigInteger Weight { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter("uint256", "creationDate", 2)]
    public BigInteger CreationDate { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter("address", "producer", 3)]
    public string Producer { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter("string", "drugName", 4)]
    public string DrugName { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter("uint256", "token", 5)]
    public BigInteger Id { get; set; }
}
```

Would suggest to use nethereum **code generation** tools to generate C# code:
https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/nethereum-code-generation/